# Redirect URL with Location header, passing other data

Tags: jsp

Using JSP, I have a need to redirect to another page after doing some basic checks. The target URL needs to be given some additional data (related to the checks made). One obvious way is this:

```
String extraData = [calculate extra data];
response.setHeader("Loction", "target.jsp?extradata=" + extraData);
```

However, I do not want to expose the extra data to the user in the browser's address box.

Since all this is in JSP, another option is to set a session attribute:

```
String extraData = [calculate extra data];
session.setAttribute("extradata", extraData);
response.setHeader("Location", "target.jsp");
```

And then target.jsp can get the extra data from the session attribute.

However, the target file might be on another server, which of course will not share the same session.

Is there some other way I can redirect to another URL and pass on extra data not in the URL itself? For example, is there any way to perhaps define additional headers that will be delivered in the HttpServletRequest to the target URL?

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom headers to the response. These headers will be sent to the recipient and therefore can be read from the headers of the response.

```
 response.addHeader(name, value);
 request.getRequestDispatcher("target.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

However this cannot extend outside the current servlet context. If you use a redirect:

```
  response.sendRedirect("target.jsp");
```

the headers are lost.

Alternatively, you could encode the data in the URL in order to hide it from plain sight. This would require it to be decoded by the recipient page on the client side.

Using AJAX might help hide the data. If when the page on the other server is redirected to (as above) it makes an AJAX call to another servlet on your server that responds with the data you want to send it encapsulated in the response.

Comment: Many thanks for the response. Unfortunately the target page is in a different application, so the headers don't get passed through. I suspect I'm going to have to just pass the data through in the URL.

Comment: Passing the data as parameters would be the simplest solution and if the data is not sensitive it shouldn't be a problem. By the way, if you do come up with a better solution post it here, I'd be interested to know it.